# Can i play sound on individual earphone(R or L) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

We can play sound on Android by using the Media Player, but i want a sound to occur only on one side of the ear phone, say only Left ear piece.
and different sound when something is triggered on the right earpiece.
Is this possible?
Can we make the sound play only one one side of the earphone when needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaPlayer has a setVolume method that takes two arguments, leftVolume and rightVolume.

[SoundPool Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setVolume(int, float, float))

Comment: I did try the setVolume method. MediaPlayer mySound;
    
        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
        mySound.setVolume(5,0);
    }

    public void PLayMusic (View view){ //button click
        mySound.start();
    }
    // BUT THE SOUND DOES NOT PLAY IN LEFT EARPEICE, IT PLAYS ON BOTH.

Comment: Thanks a million, I had to add (1.0f, 0.0f).